# In Azure DevOps, how to query user stories that were not completed and are carried over to current sprint iteration?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm trying to list user stories that were not completed and are carried over to current sprint using a better method than what I had currently made. The output should list user stories that were created not in the current sprint iteration and also it must be at least activated once in any previous iterations to be listed. My output is correct but the problem is that I have to change the date manually since I use the create date field and just set it manually to be greater than the start date of my current sprint iteration. Is there another way that I can detect if the user story was ever in a previous sprint iteration so I can list those if they are carried over to the current sprint? I was thinking something like comparing the create date of the stories so that the new stories won't be listed but I haven't found the right parameters.

[image: My inefficient query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you use the best way. You can add the date macros (like @StartOfWeek-1) that helps to analyse your user stories without changing dates in your query ([Start of Day, Week, Month, or Year date-based queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#start-of-day-week-month-or-year-date-based-queries)). Additionally, you can use the Power BI reporting where you can analyse each history revision of work items and find previous iterations. [Connect to Analytics with Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/active-bugs-sample-report?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I did actually use but it will still have its limitation if the sprint is longer than, in my case here 2 weeks. By just using the query, is there anyway to do something like : create date<start of current iteration.

Comment: @awk1912 You can simply filter like `create date < 'the specific date'` in the WIQL 
 query, for example you just need to add another filter condition `AND [System.CreatedDate] < '2019-10-10'`, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot achieve that by the built-in work item query, however we can achieve that by calling the REST APIs in a script ([Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [Revisions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)).

Please try the following PowerShell script which works for me: (you can also export the list to a CSV file, then open with Microsoft Excel)

It query the not completed `User Story` from current iteration of the specific team, then retrieve the work item revisions for each of them to detect the `System.IterationPath` field to get all the values. If the field has more than one unique values, then that means the work item is carried from previous iterations to current sprint iteration:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}", 
   [string]$projectName = "project name",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password/PAT"  
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))


# Query the work items with wiql
$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1"


function CreateJsonBody
{
    $value = @"
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State],[System.Tags] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.State] <> 'Closed' AND [System.State] <> 'Removed' AND [System.IterationPath] = @currentIteration('[Agile-0219]\Agile-0219 Team') order by [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}

"@
 return $value
}
$json = CreateJsonBody

#Get the urls for WIs
$queryresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$wiurls = $queryresult.workItems.url


#Filter the work items which carried from other iterations to current iteration
$wis = @()
cls
foreach($wiurl in $wiurls){

#Set the work item revision URL
$revurl = "$wiurl/revisions"

$wi = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $revurl -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

#Detect the Unique iterations which the work item ever been involved  
$iterationcount = ($wi.value.fields.'System.IterationPath'|select -Unique).count
#write-host $iterationcount

if ($iterationcount -gt 1) # Filter the work items which moved from other iterations
    { 
      # Select the latest revision 
       $wilatest = ($wi.value | Select -last 1) 

        $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WitID" = $wilatest.id
          "Title" = $wilatest.fields.'System.Title'
          "AssignedTo" = $wilatest.fields.'System.AssignedTo'.displayName
          "ChangedDate" = $wilatest.fields.'System.ChangedDate'
          "ChangedBy" = $wilatest.fields.'System.ChangedBy'.displayName
          "WorkItemType" = $wilatest.fields.'System.WorkItemType'
          "State" = $wilatest.fields.'System.State'
          "URL" = $wilatest.url
        } 

    $wis += $customObject   
    }

}
    $wis | Select-Object `
                WitID,
                Title, 
                AssignedTo,
                ChangedDate, 
                ChangedBy,
                WorkItemType,
                State,
                URL #|export-csv -Path D:\sample.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to filter by created date in the query, then you just need to add the the filter condition like: `AND [System.CreatedDate] < '2019-10-10'`

So, the query should be :

```
"Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State],[System.Tags] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.State] <> 'Closed' AND [System.State] <> 'Removed' AND [System.IterationPath] = @currentIteration AND [System.CreatedDate] < '2019-10-10' order by [System.CreatedDate] desc"
```

Comment: sorry if my next question is too basic but how do you do a rest api call?

Comment: @awk1912 The above script is just a sample which calling the REST APIs in powersehll, you just need to copy the script and replace the parameters accordingly,  then run in powershell directly, or you can create a `*.txt` file, then copy and past the script, replace the parameters, then save , then change `*.txt` to `*.ps`, then double click to run the script directly to get the result.

Comment: @awk1912 Any update here? Have you tried the script with the query? is it working for you?

Comment: will update asap when I try your method, currently I modified it with startOfDate field so I that I just need to change that field not every sprint but just when the sprint is at longer/shorter duration

Comment: My goal is very similar & a bit more broad. I think this query is on the right track. The only thing I would suggest is a "Work Item Revisions". This endpoint will allow you to see if it was in a previous sprint and if it wasn't closed the current sprint. But the query gets complicated.... (which is where I am stuck at right now). Good luck!